# Issue while installing NuGet package Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Iam making a android project with Azure mobile services in Xamarin. I want to install the latest version of the Azure mobile services NuGet package. But I get a error saying :-

```
NuGet.NuGetVersionNotSatisfiedException: The 'Microsoft.Bcl 1.1.9' package requires NuGet client version '2.8.1' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.7.2.0'.
```

I am new at using Xamarin. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio you will need to upgrade the NuGet extension to the latest version 2.8.1. Open Tools - Extensions and Updates - Updates. There should be an updated NuGet Package Manager extension available.

If you are using Xamarin Studio 4 you should upgrade the [NuGet addi](https://github.com/mrward/monodevelop-nuget-addin)n or upgrade to Xamarin Studio 5.